# LINQ query to DataTable type error

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable, types

I have the following function in by Data Access Layer but I am receiving the following error on my RETURN statement.

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly

My code is:

```
DL.FVRGDataContext db = new FVRGDataContext();

public DataTable getRestaurants(string cuisineName)
{
   var cuisineIdFind = from CUISINE in db.CUISINEs
                       where CUISINE.CUISINE_NAME == cuisineName
                       select CUISINE.CUISINE_ID;

   var restaurantList = from RESTAURANT in db.RESTAURANTs
                        where RESTAURANT.CUISINE_ID == 2
                        orderby RESTAURANT.REST_NAME ascending
                        select i;

   DataTable result = new DataTable();
   result = restaurantList.CopyToDataTable();

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised the `restaurantList` assignment didn't fail - what's `i` that you're selecting here?

Comment: And **why on earth** do you grab a list of `Restaurant` using LINQ, only to then convert it back to a klunky, hard to use `DataTable` ..... doesn't make any sense at all to me - but that's just me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CopyToDataTable` doesn't work this way... it has a generic parameter `T`, where `T` must be a subclass of `DataRow`. In other words `CopyToDataTable` can't be used to convert an arbitrary collection to `DataTable`, the items of the collection must be `DataRows` themselves.

In your case, `CUISINE` and `RESTAURANT` seem to be Linq to SQL or Entity Framework entities, not `DataRows`, so it can't work.